# Method does not exist in the current context because it is in another file(C#)

Tags: c#, class, methods

currently i have a stack of methods inside my BotUtility.cs file. I want
to execute these methods from another file (Dispatchbot.cs) but they dont exist in the current
context. But why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also add using SEKAI.BotUtility;

Comment: Post your code. Images don't show up for many people, including me.

Answer (score 0):

Your current context is the class DispatchBot, that's where you are getting the error. The Method you want to call is in a different class named BotUtility.

Therefore as Kalten already mentioned you need to call it by changing your instruction to:

```
BotUtility.CreateAdaptiveCard(WelcomeCardpath)
```

The compiler shows you the error, because that method could exit in multiple classes. Which one should it pick? That's why you need to clearly identify which method you want to call by adding the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Add `using SEKAI.BotUtility;` on top of `DispatchBot.cs` class and call the function using `BotUtility.CreateAdaptiveCard(WelcomeCardpath)` in line #44

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
namespace //Namespace name
{
    public class DispatchBot : BotUtility
    {    
       void DispatchBotFunction()
       {
           BotUtlityFunction();
       }
    }
}
```

Note: If this not work this issue might be because the folder that the Classes are, are different.